# How to prevent AngularJS from validating form controls for the first time

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, ng-pattern

I my form I have some input controls which are bounded with controller's scope data. Based on users selection I am bounding selected item by using ng-model to input controls.

I am validating those inputs by using ng-maxlength ,minlength ,ng-pattern and other inbuilt validation directives.

Class for highlighting the invalid values.

```
.ng-invalid { border-color:red; }
```

But when user wants to add a new product, then I am creating an empty object and adding it to controller's scope data.

At the very first time while creating new item I don't want to highlight every thing with  red, because very thing is empty.

Is there any way by which I can highlight invalid input on their focus and after it will show as invalid until use put some valid values in it.

When use select any existing data then I am validating control at that movement.

Comment: Provide the rest of the code too.

Comment: @Claies i am adding object with properties and their values are undefined  by default.

Comment: @Claies adding object with no properties also not working.

Comment: without showing the code you are using to create the new object, and the HTML with the validation rules on it, it's difficult to know what to suggest.

Comment: you can use chained css, i.e. `.ng-dirty.ng-invalid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forms' `$pristine` as a condition for your classes.